# Finding text in a XML Node using Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-xml

i am trying to parse an xml nd comparing its text with input fields  but its not working here is the code i have tried..

```
 $('#finish').click(function() {
 var email = document.getElementById('email').value
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('child[name="Email"]').each(function(){
                var i = $(this).attr('text');
                if(i == email)
                alert('email already registered');
                else{
                activity.SubmitData();
                }

            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email..">
<button id="finish" >Register</button>
```

**XML**

```
<reg>
  <user>
    <Name> myName</Name>
    <Email> myEmail </Email>
    <Date> 22/12/2013 </Date>
  </user>
</reg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#finish').click(function () {
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            //check if any Email element has the entered email as its value
            var valid = $(xml).find('Email').filter(function () {
                return $.trim($(this).text()) == email
            }).length == 0;
            //if valid submit the data
            if (valid) {
                activity.SubmitData();
            } else {
                alert('email already registered');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i have used your code, but the control is not going to this function now, i have checked it on firefox debugger....

Comment: @AdilWaqar not going to which function? is there any error in your browser console

Comment: no there is no error, but when i click the button  the event is not fired ... $('#finish').click(function ()

Comment: @AdilWaqar was it firing before

Comment: can you add `alert($('#finish').length)` before `$('#finish').click(function () {...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==` for comparison:

```
if(i == email)
```

Also, your input does not have `text` attribute so `var i = $(this).attr('text');` will not work as expected. You're probably want to get its type instead:

```
var i = $(this).attr('type');
```

or if you want to get its text then use `.text()`:

```
var i = $(this).text();
```

if you want to remove the trailing spaces from the text, then you can use `$.trim()`:

```
var i = $.trim($(this).text());
```

Comment: What is `var i = $(this).attr('text');` return here? Your input does not have `text` attrribute.

Comment: Seem like you want to get its type instead: `var i = $(this).attr('type');`

Comment: or if you want to get its text then use: `var i = $(this).text();`